# Docker and how to update debian with updated Nginx.. doesn't build

Tags: nginx, docker

- I am trying to use Docker and update Nginx but the build keeps failing.
- I currently have two files. I am trying to just use the Docker file, any ideas? Btw, I saw the Nginx part didn't update (in the build, still shows 1.10.3)
- the 'development' env in Dockerfile makes me think this is just for local?

docker-base/Docker file. Old. What to update the node and Nginx.

```
FROM node:10.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx build-essential gyp libpng-dev bzip2 autoconf libtool nasm libvips-dev --no-install-recommends && mkdir -p /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install -g node-gyp
```

I WANT TO REMOVE THIS AND JUSt ADD IT TO THE DOCKER FILE....

```
FROM oudatedImage 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libvips-dev --no-install-recommends

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN NODE_ENV=development npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["sh", "run_app.sh"]
```

From what I gather, an image is created from the docker-base/Docker file.. and that then is inserted into the Docker file... BUT I don't need that image or that process... I want to summarize it all in the Dockerfile.

Any ideas? I tried to update to a newer version of node stretch, but the Nginx wouldn't update and the build failed. Any ideas on combining the two in the Dockerfile and updating node and Nginx?

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: 1) Are you running unmanaged Docker on a GCE VM instance?; 2) Do you want to use an image from an external container registry and get Nginx upgraded inside of it?

Comment: there are other images on the GCE vm instance... but those are terribly out of date... I tried using what i have an just update the base image... and add a version to the nginx ala..

FROM node:14.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx=1.17.0

and in the Docker: FROM gcr.io/SITE/base:14.0

But that didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current description, it looks to me as if you had some setup that builds an image based on the first file, pushes it into GCR and then uses it as base for the second. So, I'm assuming you're aware of this, you understand your system/pipeline and you know that the community doesn't have access to your environment to assess it.

Now, your questions are: How to update Nginx, Node and how to have everything in one Dockerfile.

```
# Use the latest base image
FROM node:latest

# Adding this here bc is only relevant for your environment
ARG NODE_ENV='production'
ARG CLIENT_HOST='cdn.mysite.com'
ARG PORT='80'
ARG HOST='www.mysite.com'
ARG API_HOST='api.mysite.com'
ARG API2_HOST='api2.mysite.com'
ARG PROTOCOL='https'
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
ENV CLIENT_HOST $CLIENT_HOST
ENV PROTOCOL $PROTOCOL
ENV API2_HOST $API2_HOST
ENV API_HOST $API_HOST
ENV HOST $HOST
ENV PORT $PORT

# Adding the new mainline package for Stretch to match the Node Docker image and adding the signing keys
RUN echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx \
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list && wget -qO - https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -

# Your package dependencies + latest Nginx
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y nginx build-essential gyp libpng-dev bzip2 autoconf libtool nasm libvips-dev --no-install-recommends && mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Appending the GCR file build steps
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN NODE_ENV=development npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["sh", "run_app.sh"]
```

**Explanation**

Basically, the Node image comes with an outdated Nginx version so you need to follow the [offical Nginx repo update](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#installing-a-prebuilt-ubuntu-package-from-the-official-nginx-repository).

As you can see in the Dockerfile, I just added these actions in a `RUN` step before installing all the packages.

As for the Node version, you're running an [outdated version not even listed in Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node), so I just used the latest one.

As of this writing, it should have Nginx 1.17.10 and Node v14.3.0

About the `ARG` directives, these have your [custom default values](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#default-values) that seem to be only relevant in your context so I'm just including them there as is impossible for the community to know if they're related to errors in your pipeline.

Finally, if the build fails, you need to provide the error to get a more accurate answer or to clarify your whole context and be specific on what you need.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks a bunch!!!!!

Comment: hey @yyyyahir can you tell me what this does: apt-key add - ?